# Stripe plan enrollment and receipt email

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm creating customers in Stripe (using test mode) with recurring plans and email addresses.  So far, everything works as I'd expect: when a customer is created and enrolled in a recurring plan, they are automatically charged for the first period of the plan.  What I have is almost verbatim [what is in the tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/subscriptions).  The plan names differ, and the costs differ, but other than that, it's more or less copy/paste.

However, even with the customer enrolled with email set and the Stripe account set up to send customer receipts on charges, the receipt email from Stripe are not being sent.  It's not clear to me why this would be, especially since I'm under the impression that Stripe should send email when *any* charge is made if "Email customers for Successful Payments" is checked, even when in test mode (per [the support site](https://support.stripe.com/questions/email-receipts)).

Looking at the invoice dashboard, it looks like receipt emails are not being sent per the receipt history, leading me to believe that something I have done is incorrect.

Why is Stripe not sending email upon a successful charge?  What have I missed?

Comment: Came here from a similar error, if you're getting `[Error: Received unknown parameter: receipt_email]` from the Stripe Javascript API then the answer below is for you :) (adding comment for googleability)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Stripe doesn't send email receipts in Test mode at the moment and it's mentioned in the support article you [linked](https://support.stripe.com/questions/email-receipts):

> As a note, we’ll only send email receipts for payments that are made with your live API key or through your live dashboard. If you’d like to see what a test email receipt looks like, you can click the “View Receipt” link on a live or test payment’s page. You can also send a test email from your email settings.

Comment: I flat out overlooked it.  Thanks for pointing it out, even if I feel silly. :)